# How does an index speed up insertion in a table

Tags: oracle, index, index-tuning, clustered-index

How does index speed up insertion in a table?

I have an idea how it happens for retrieving the rows and selection of data, but how does it helps in insertion?

```
CREATE TABLE  persons(
id NUMBER ,
first_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

and if create an index on first_name

```
create index name_idx on persons(first_name)
```

how does it speed up the query below?

```
INSERT INTO suppliers (id,first_name) VALUES (01, 'SAI');
INSERT INTO suppliers (id,first_name) VALUES (02, 'CHRI');
INSERT INTO suppliers (id,first_name) VALUES (03, 'MASSEY');
INSERT INTO suppliers (id,first_name) VALUES (04, 'FREDDIE');
INSERT INTO suppliers (id,first_name) VALUES (05, 'ROGER');
```

Comment: It won't speed up the insert: it will slow it down. Each insert will also require updating the index.

Comment: "*how does it speed up the query below*" - it doesn't. It only makes it slower

Answer (score 6):

An index like that with an `INSERT` like this only makes the `INSERT` slower.

An index could help if you performed an `INSERT .. SELECT .. FROM ...` and the index would speed up the `SELECT` part.

Comment: The speed up comment applies to an index on the table being selected from and not the table being inserted to. In addition, the index would probably not be used with the query as shown unless a `where` clause was used or if the index was covering.